# is text input correct and can table layout be changed slightly

Tags: php, html

I have 2 small questions I need help on which deals with the code below:

```
echo "<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
      <tr>
      <th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
      <th class='questionth'>Question</th>
      <th class='answerth'>Answer</th>
      <th class='answermarksth'>Marks per Answer</th>
      <th class='noofmarksth'>Total Marks</th>
      </tr>\n";
                $previous_question_id = null;
          foreach ($searchQuestionContent as $key=>$question) {
            if ($previous_question_id == $searchQuestionId[$key]) {
          $searchQuestionId[$key] = '';
          $question = '';
          $searchMarks[$key] = '';
      }else{
          $previous_question_id = $searchQuestionId[$key];
      }
        echo '<tr class="questiontd">'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td class="optiontypetd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchQuestionId[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td class="answertd">';
        echo $searchAnswer[$key];
        echo '</td>' ;
        echo '<td class="answermarkstd"><input class="individualMarks" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" "/></td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td class="noofmarkstd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchMarks[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
}      
        echo '</tr>';
        echo "</table>" . PHP_EOL;
```

Question 1: If you look at the table above, I have a a column where it will contain text inputs. Now each text input will belong to each answer in the "Answer" column. My question is that is the text input set up correctly with me including a [] in the `name` attribute to set up an array? Should I include `[]` and is there anything else I should include in the text input code?

Question 2: At the moment the code above makes the table look like this example in [JSFIDDLE1](http://jsfiddle.net/6jpwY/7/). But I want the table to be displayed as this example [JSFIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/6jpwY/10/). As you can see the blank rows in the other table have been rowspan so that it looks like the question and the total marks looks like its in one cell. How can I get the table above to look like JSFIDDLE2?

UPDATE:

Below is the full code, I am still receiving undefined index whenver `$rowspans[....` is used. Is the code below correct:

```
$assessment = $_SESSION['id'] . $sessionConcat;

$query = "SELECT q.SessionId, s.SessionName, q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, an.Answer, q.QuestionMarks 
FROM Session s 
INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId AND an.SessionId = q.SessionId
WHERE s.SessionName = ?
ORDER BY q.QuestionId, an.Answer
";

// prepare query
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$stmt->bind_param("s", $assessment);
// execute query
$stmt->execute(); 


// This will hold the search results
$searchQuestionId = array();
$searchQuestionContent = array();
$searchAnswer = array();
$searchMarks = array();

// Fetch the results into an array

// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$stmt->bind_result($dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, $dbQuestionId, $dbQuestionContent, $dbAnswer, $dbQuestionMarks);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
$searchQuestionId[] = $dbQuestionId;
$searchQuestionContent[] = $dbQuestionContent;
$searchAnswer[] = $dbAnswer;
$searchMarks[] = $dbQuestionMarks;
}   

?>      

</head>

<body>

<form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">


<?php 

echo "<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
<tr>
<th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
<th class='questionth'>Question</th>
<th class='answerth'>Answer</th>
<th class='noofmarksth'>Total Marks</th>
</tr>\n";
$previous_question_id = null;
$rowspans = array_count_values($searchQuestionId);
foreach ($searchQuestionContent as $key=>$question) {
if ($previous_question_id == $searchQuestionId[$key]) {
$searchQuestionId[$key] = '';
$question = '';
$searchMarks[$key] = '';
}else{
$previous_question_id = $searchQuestionId[$key];
}
echo '<tr class="questiontd">'.PHP_EOL;
echo '<td class="optiontypetd">'.htmlspecialchars($rowspans[$searchQuestionId[$key]]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '<td class="answertd">';
echo $searchAnswer[$key];
echo '</td>';        echo '<td class="noofmarkstd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchMarks[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</tr>';
echo "</table>" . PHP_EOL;

?>

<p><input id="submitBtn" name="submitMarks" type="submit" value="Submit Marks" /></p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. Yes, you could even specify a name between the `[]`.

Q2. It seems that `$searchQuestionId` is filled before your loop, right? In that case you could use [`array_count_values`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to store the frequency of each ID and access that array during the loop:

before your loop: `$rowspans = array_count_values($searchQuestionId);`

access rowspan value during loop with: `$rowspans[$searchQuestionId[$key]]`.

You'll have to remove the line `$searchQuestionId[$key] = '';` or else you won't be able to access the correct `$rowspan` key.

Finally, you'll have to set up some more `if` statements to skip the `<td>`s on certain rows.

```
$previous_question_id = null;
$rowspans = array_count_values($searchQuestionId);
foreach ($searchQuestionContent as $key=>$question) {

    // removed logic, not necessary to set empty strings if you're skipping them

    echo '<tr class="questiontd">'.PHP_EOL;

    if ($previous_question_id != $searchQuestionId[$key]) {
        echo '<td class="optiontypetd" rowspan="'.$rowspans[$searchQuestionId[$key]].'">'.htmlspecialchars($searchQuestionId[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td rowspan="'.$rowspans[$searchQuestionId[$key]].'">'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo '<td class="answertd">';
    echo $searchAnswer[$key];
    echo '</td>' ;
    echo '<td class="answermarkstd"><input class="individualMarks" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" "/></td>' . PHP_EOL;

    if ($previous_question_id != $searchQuestionId[$key]) {
        echo '<td class="noofmarkstd" rowspan="'.$rowspans[$searchQuestionId[$key]].'">'.htmlspecialchars($searchMarks[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    // moved this to the end
    if ($previous_question_id != $searchQuestionId[$key]) {
        $previous_question_id = $searchQuestionId[$key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, It is giving me an undefined index for line 45 when I tested your code, I included an update in my question, can you look at the update code and just see if that code is correct and the way you want me to write it? I added a comment to show which line is showing the notice

Comment: I meant those two solutions to be separate. Sorry, I should have been clearer. Is `$searchQuestionId` in fact filled elsewhere? If so you don't need to use that first block I posted.

Comment: So for the second solution should `$rowspans[$searchQuestionId[$key]]` be in both the if and else statement?

Comment: No, I meant that you don't need my first block at all if `$searchQuestionId` contains the list of IDs beforehand. You can leave your loop as-is, and access the rowspan value with `$rowspans[$searchQuestionId[$key]]`. I'll edit my answer to remove the first block.

Comment: I will post in my update code on 2nd solution, problem is that I am getting undefined index errors for this solution but it just says `Notice: Undefined index: in ... on line 144 ` It doesn't say what is undefined

Comment: Oh sorry I think I might know what you mean, sorry let me just try again and I get back to you. You mean leave the foreach loop, put `$rowspans = array_count_values($searchQuestionId);` and then do `echo '<td class="optiontypetd">'.htmlspecialchars($rowspans[$searchQuestionId[$key]]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;`

Comment: Can you post the code that shows where `$searchQuestionId` gets filled, and/or post its contents?

Comment: I have posted what the whole current code looks like in the UPDATE. At the top is the query and you will be able to see where `$searchQuestionId` comes from, then you will see the foreach loop and table at bottom of the code

Comment: I edited my answer again to (hopefully) include the working code. The notice you were seeing was because of setting empty string, but I added more as well.

Comment: Perfect, absolutely perfect. Thank you very much :)